# Python pytz: Show the actual time in a timezone

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I am trying to convert a datetime from UTC to another timezone. But after the conversion, the time component is not changing. Instead it's adding the offset time along with the timezone.

Is there any way I can display the actual time in that timezone?

Sample code:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> today=datetime.datetime.now()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 0, 50, 33, 294610)
>>> today.isoformat()
'2019-04-18T00:50:33.294610'
>>> today2=today.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore'))
>>> today2
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 0, 50, 33, 294610, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Singapore' +08+8:00:00 STD>)
>>> today2.isoformat()
'2019-04-18T00:50:33.294610+08:00'
>>> today2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2019-04-18 00:50:33'
>>>
```

I expect `today2` variable to print: `2019-04-18T08:50:33.294610`

I tried formatting the date using `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`, but it's still showing me `2019-04-18 00:50:33`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Try `today.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Singapore')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` to display the datetime in the specific time zone you want. Remember that the datetime value is always stored in UTC so anytime you want to convert for display, you need to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, note that I set the `tzinfo=None` to remove the `+08:00`

```
In [102]: today2.replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()                                                                                    
Out[102]: '2019-04-18T01:10:32.226014'

In [103]: today2.isoformat()                                                                                                         
Out[103]: '2019-04-18T01:10:32.226014+08:00'
```

Comment: Still getting same output.. I expect today2 be like 2019-04-19 00:26:54   ```>>> today2=today.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore'))
>>> today2
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 20, 26, 54, 333026, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Singapore' +08+8:00:00 STD>)
'2019-04-18T20:26:54.333026+08:00'
>>> today2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2019-04-18 20:26:54'
>>>
>>> today2.replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
'2019-04-18T20:26:54.333026'
>>> today2.isoformat()
'2019-04-18T20:26:54.333026+08:00'```

Comment: I gave the answer for python3.x. Are you using that?